# Is it possible to instantiate an object of one class in two different ways?

Tags: python, object, methods, instantiation

[Here](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) is an example which creates a point as `p=Point(x, y)`. Assume that I have some array `ppp=(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are numbers and I want to make it of class `Point` but in the way: `p=Point(ppp)`. I can do either one or another way but not both simultaneously. Is it possible to have both ways?

Comment: The proposed solution does not work for me. I have:
`def __init__(self, x, y = None, z = None):
        if y is not None and z is not None:
            self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        elif y is not None or z is not None:
            raise TypeError('Instance may have only 1 or 3 arguments, got 2')
        else:
            self.x, self.y, self.z = x`
Then I make: `ppp = Point(p)`, where `p = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`, and I got: `__new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)`. It does not matter what are the numbers inside.

Comment: The solution of Karol Nowak works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *know* that you have a tuple/list while creating the instance, you can do: `p = Point(*ppp)`, where `ppp` is the tuple.

Comment: It should:


    >>> class Point(object):
    ...     def __init__(self, x, y):
    ...             self.x = x
    ...             self.y = y
    ...
    >>> coords = [1, 2]
    >>> p = Point(*coords)
    >>> p
    <__main__.Point object at 0x7ff4a6ec>
    >>> p.x, p.y
    (1, 2)

Comment: It means "unpack the list/tuple into multiple arguments". And if you have a `dict` `d`, you can use `**d` to unpack it into keyword arguments.

Comment: What is the difference between `init__` and `__init__`? If I use `__init__` the code does not work.

Comment: @AlexPi: The inital `__` was interpreted as bold markup by the markdown formatting code. The commenter did put them in but did not escape them. `init__` doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways to acquire the result, the first is to analyse arguments that you pass to __init__ and in dependence of their quantity and type - choose a decision what are you using to instantiate class.

```
class Point(object):

    x = 0
    y = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y=None):
       if y is None:
           self.x, self.y = x, x
       else:
           self.x, self.y = x, y
```

The other decision is to use classmethods as instantiators:

```
class Point(object):

    x = 0
    y = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_coords(cls, x, y):
       inst = cls()
       inst.x = x
       inst.y = y
       return inst

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, x):
       inst = cls()
       inst.x, inst.y = x, x
       return inst

p1 = Point.from_string('1.2 4.6')
p2 = Point.from_coords(1.2, 4.6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean, and I considered this way. But I did not want to create too many methods, and then call them every time I need to make a Point. The first way is better for me.

Comment: The second method is much cleaner.  Branching to determine type identity just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y=None):
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            self.x, self.y = x
         else:
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
```

Comment: does it work only if the array is tuple? What if I have a list? The second answer is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y=None):
        if y is not None:
            self.x, self.y = x, y
        else:
            self.x, self.y = x

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, {}".format(self.x, self.y)

print Point(1,2)
# 1, 2
print Point((1,2))
# 1, 2
```

Comment: This won't work if `y==0`.  You should use `if y is not None`, I think.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that your looking for a way to overload your constructor, as is common in statically typed languages such as C++ and Java.

This is not possible in Python. What you can do is provide different keyword argument combinations, something like:

```
class Point(object):
  def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, r=None, t=None):
    if x is not None and y is not None:
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
    elif r is not None and t is not None:
      # set cartesian coordinates from polar ones
```

Which you would then use as:

```
p1 = Point(x=1, y=2)
p2 = Point(r=1, t=3.14)
```

Comment: That is an interesting application.